# Integrating Piecewise

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:=[0,6] \to [0,2]$.

$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 x&\text{if}\, 0\leq x\leq 2\\
 2&\text{if}\, 2<x\leq 6\\
\end{cases}
$

Find a solution $y:[0,6)\to\Bbb R$ of IVP $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x),y(0)=2$

I decided to consider the two cases, so first when $0\leq x\leq 2\\$. I used the boundary condition to reach $y=\frac{x^2}{2}+2$ for $0\leq x\leq 2$.

When $2< x\leq 6$, $y=2x+C$ where $C$ is a real number.

So my final solution is:
$y:[0,6)\to\Bbb R,\quad
y(x):=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{x^2}{2}+2&\text{if}\, 0\leq x\leq 2\\
 2x+C&\text{if}\, 2<x\leq 6\\
\end{cases}
$

Where have I gone wrong ?

Comment: $y$ should be continuous at $2$. Hence $C=?$

Comment: Hi :) It's not wrong, but you have to compute $C$. It's possible. At least $y$ has to be continuous, if it is differentiable.

Comment: @Fred Ohhh I get it, so the values at $x=2$ must match for the two separate cases right for $f$ to be continuous

Comment: @Jochen So that would make $C=0$

Comment: Yes, we have $C=0.$

Comment: @Fred $y$ is differentiable because we have assumed it is a solution on $[0,2]$ right. I guess more simply because it contains differentiable functions itself polynomials ?